# Using UIPickerView to populate UITextView within a UIViewController .xib framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uipickerview

Let me preface by saying that I am completely new to programming.  I have also done a bunch of searching on this issue and haven't found an answer that seems to address exactly what I am doing.

The result I am looking for is a text field that can be populated by the user by using a pickerView.  After putting a UITextView box in the .xib file I am not sure how make it call a pickerView when tapped and then populate from that picker view.

Thank you for any help given.  Let me know if I need to clarify more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `UIPickerView` and set it as the `inputView` property of your `UITextView`. Then, register your class for the `dataSource`/`delegate` of the `UIPickerView` to populate it and know when it has changed selection. Below is a simple solution for a picker with a single component.

**SomeViewController.h**:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView *picker;
    NSArray *dataSource;
}
```

**SomeViewController.m**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;

    myTextView.inputView = picker;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [dataSource count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [dataSource objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [myTextView setText:[dataSource objectAtIndex:row]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  How do I actually pick the object in the array and have it populate the text field?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say "pick the object in the array"

Comment: Well, I would like the text field to be populated by my choice in the pickerView.  I used the code you gave and can pull up the pickerView, but I am not sure how to dismiss it and have my choice populate the text field.

Comment: Whenever you stop the picker's "wheel" on any row, it should be populating your text view. That's what happens in the picker's `didSelectRow` delegate method. If nothing is happening in your text view, make sure it's hooked up properly in your xib. To dismiss, there are some options- gesture recognizer on the view that will resign first responder when tapping outside your text view, cancel/done button in your nav bar, custom toolbar on the picker with a done button...

Comment: Thanks Stonz!  Figured it out.

Comment: If your problem has been addressed, please consider marking the question as answered so that it closes.